# Why is my wordpress website is suddenly showing as a index list?

Tags: wordpress, indexing

My website is already live for a long time. suddenly yesterday he open as a list seems like index.

www.gilron.org

Why is that?
(i don't have any cache plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The console is showing an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fitVids is not a function
```

This error indicated that most probably you have disables the FitVids plugin or some upgrade on the template might have removed it.

I see no js library included with the Fitvids plugin.

Documentation of the fitvids plugin on their github page.

https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the comment.  apparently, the command who call the css.style inside the header was deleted. fixed it. solved!